# Turn dictionary into custom type

Tags: swift, dictionary, deserialization

I turn all my custom classes into dictionaries using Mirror in order to save them with a plist like structure. With the Mirrors I simply store each value by its name, so a class with a variable "title" would turn into a dictionary with the key "title" and its value in the dictionary.

The question is, how to reverse this? I store a "type" information in every dictionary so I know which type should a dictionary turn into, but I don't know how to do the transition. I used to make use of `setValue: forKey:` in Objective-C but as I moved to Swift I have many structs for which this no longer works.

The only solution I can think of is to have all custom types conform to a protocol that describes an `init(dictionary: [String: Any])` function and then manually translate the dictionary into the type there. In my general converter function I then get the type and through a switch statement simply call the init on the right type. It seems downright stupid though, to manually write

```
title = dictionary["title"]
```

for the thousands of properties I have throughout the whole app. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by tbogosia I looked at what Swift 4 offers and it looks like the new `Codable` is the way to go.

Apple doc right here:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

It would seem that for lower version of Swift there is no other option but to use custom `init` functions for every custom type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the option you've laid out is an okay one. I would recommend using an optional init, like `init?(dictionary: [String: Any])`, if you're going to do that so you can ensure that certain key-value pairs are available, and return nil if your final object is incomplete.

However, it sounds like you could definitely benefit from something like [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) or [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper), which both do handle serialization nicely.

Comment: Thanks tbogoisa for the links. I am not a big fan of using external libraries if it can be avoided, especially with swift which changes all the time. Having said that, as a last resort it is better than nothing. As for the init, well it works, true, but my issue is that I have many structs with many variables all named exactly as the keys in the dictionaries, it seems almost pointless to write all that code so I am hoping for a general method that takes care of it all. With Mirror doing what it does, it seems hard to believe there is none.

Comment: Well, you're (semi) in luck. While I don't believe what your describing is a language feature at the moment, Apple announced at WWDC this year that object serialization will better supported in the next updates.

https://medium.com/@vonkunesnewton/thoughts-after-two-days-of-wwdc-2017-1b7ec5b44cca